# implementing long pull / comet in simple javascript no frameworks require XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, comet, long-polling

I have my own stripped down script that currently makes uses of XHR or script tags depending on browser support. These requests ultimately return some JSON.  My problem is now elements of this object now need to be updated by the server while on the client i.e. i need to implement some kinda of long pull/comet soln.

Google seems to come up with lots of solns using various frameworks such as JQuery etc.. to do this on the client side. However this is not an option for me.

I was wondering if you guys had any suggestions on how I could extend my existing approach to allow comet style updates from the server. One of the standard approaches seems to be using hidden iframes. This is a no go as the app server that is providing me with my json data is different to the actual webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery simply wraps around the XHR/XMLHTTPRequest object.
First of, you need a small function to return the object in a cross-browser manner. <strike>This is done in 3 lines or less, not too difficult.</strike> That said, the are great snippets for fixing different browser issues, such as memory leaks. I highly suggest you use [this one](http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/). These of course span more than 3 lines (unless minified). But in either case, if you want repeated connections, you just can't do this from scratch.

Next, on the server side, assuming you're on PHP:

```
set_time_limit(300); // force connection only after 5 minutes
ignore_user_abort(false); // if the connection ends, terminate immediately

while(true){
    if(some_condition()){
        echo some_response();
        break; // break the loop
    }
    sleep(2); // wait for a second or two
}
```

Client side, just repeat the query whenever the connection ends. At this point, also handle the output.

Clients-side example:

```
function poll(){
    jQuery.get('http://somesite.com/poll.php',function(data){
        alert('Just received: '+data);
        poll(); // repeat poll
    });
}
poll(); // begin polling
```

Comment: Christian can you elaborate a little on how I'd implement what you say on the client side.

Comment: See my revised code. Although in jQuery, it should be easy to convert to plain javascript.